# SQL WHERE clause to return more than MAX() value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with 5 million records. There's a field that stores an integer value for the year the record relates to with a value range of 2010-2024. I'm trying to think through an expression so that I get a resulting table of all records with the 5 highest years. So basically, any record with 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, or 2024. I can define that explicitly in a where statement, but is there a way to not have to hard code this using MAX() and then putting that in a where statement along with MAX() - 1, MAX() - 2, etc?

Though MAX() returns a single value; I want all records showing the max and the other highest 4 values.

The year var isn't a date field, it's an integer var that stores a year value. This will be sufficient, but what I was really looking for was the five highest values. So if the range of values was (2020, 2010, 2008, 2004, 2000, 1992, 1981, 1970), it would return all records with values of (2020, 2010, 2008, 2004, and 2000), not (2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016) cause those wouldn't exist other than 2020.

Comment: depending on rdbms perhaps `YourField >= year(now())-1`  the system function year() returns the year portion of the now() function (aka current date).  We subtract 4 from it and we get current year and prior 4.  so the quesiton depends on the RDBMS.  are you using SQL Server, mySQL, Oracle, Db2 something else?  But if we say it's now 2025 and you have no 2025 records yet, then you just want `HAVING yourfield>=max(yourfield)-4`.  you can't put an aggregrate function in a where clause.  but this also means you would need a group by.

Comment: You haven't tagged your database. Depending on your database, check order by and limit or top. Looks like you don't need MAX at all. Provide sample data and desired output to make it clear.

Comment: 5 highest years starting from today or 5 highest years from the maximum date in your data? And what if there are missing years?

Comment: `MAX()` requires a grouping, so can probably do as a subquery, but if it doesn't get optimized properly it will be pretty slow

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   year >
        (
        SELECT  MAX(year) - 5
        FROM    mytable
        )
```

It will help a lot with the performance if you have an index on `mytable.year`

Note that this answers the question as asked. "all records with the 5 highest years" is quite a peculiar requirement. Usually, people want records 5 years back relative to the current date. In this case, it would be:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   year > YEAR(GETDATE()) - 5
```

---

Update after requirements change:

In SQL Server 2022+:

```
SELECT  mytable.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  TOP 5
                value AS year
        FROM    GENERATE_SERIES((SELECT MAX(year) FROM mytable), (SELECT MIN(year) FROM mytable), -1) AS q
        WHERE   EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    mytable
                WHERE   mytable.year = q.value
                )
        ORDER BY
                value DESC
        ) years
JOIN    mytable
ON      mytable.year = years.year
```

In previous versions (2008+):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  MAX(year) AS value, MIN(year) AS minvalue
        FROM    mytable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  value - 1, minvalue
        FROM    q
        WHERE   value > minvalue
        )
SELECT  mytable.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  TOP 5
                value AS year
        FROM    q
        WHERE   EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    mytable
                WHERE   mytable.year = q.value
                )
        ORDER BY
                value DESC
        ) years
JOIN    mytable
ON      mytable.year = years.year
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

These queries:

1. Generate a range of all years that your table has
2. Select 5 top years from this range
3. Join the table back to the top 5 years.

It is crucial that you have an index on `year` for these queries to work fast.

Some databases support the algorithm known as "loose index scan", or "skip scan", that would allow just doing `SELECT DISTINCT year FROM mytable` to get the list of the years.

SQL Server, unfortunately, is not one if them.

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much gives me what I need. The year var isn't a date field, it's an integer var that stores a year value. This will be sufficient, but what I was really looking for was the five highest values. So if the range of values was (2020, 2010, 2008, 2004, 2000, 1992, 1981, 1970), it would return all records with values of (2020, 2010, 2008, 2004, and 2000), not (2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016) cause those wouldn't exist other than 2020. Sorry if I'm not being clear.

Comment: @kgs_doc: what is your database engine?

Comment: SQL Server...using SSMS

Comment: @kgs_doc: please edit your post and add the clarification there. Comments are going to get deleted. Thank you.